# Strange result using a calculator

Tags: complex-numbers

I was trying to calculate : $e^{i\pi /3}$. 
So here is what I did : $e^{i\pi /3} = (e^{i\pi})^{1/3} = (-1)^{1/3} = -1$

Yet when I plug : $e^{i\pi /3}$ in my calculator it just prints : $0.5 + 0.866i$

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: You are wrong when you write $e^{i\pi /3} = (e^{i\pi})^{1/3}$. This doesn't hold, you are in the complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(e^{i\pi /3})^3=-1$, but that doesn't mean $e^{i\pi /3}=(-1)^{1/3}$. Similarly, $(-1)^2=1$, but $-1\neq1^{1/2}=1$

There are three different cubic roots of $-1$, and $-1$ is just one of them. $e^{i\pi /3}$ is another, and $e^{2i\pi /3}$ is the third one.

The problem is essentially that taking the cubic root, as taking the square root, is not strictly speaking a function. When you take the cubic root of a nonzero number, you have three possible results, and you need to choose one in order to get a function.

Your calculator simply chose $-1$ as "the" cubic root of $-1$, and "forgot to tell you" that there are two more roots.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your calculator *knows* that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, and therefore $e^{i\pi/3}=\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$.

Comment: Ok, but where I am wrong then ?

Comment: @1231 Because you are assuming that $e^{ab}=(e^a)^b$. That's true if $a$ and $b$ are real, but it does not even make sense in general.

Answer (score 0):

You take $(-1)^\frac{1}{3}=-1$. But actually, there are three numbers such that their cube is $-1$. They are $-1$, $e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}}$.

Answer (score 0):

There exist three numbers that all have the property that $z^3=- 1$.

Your calculator uses $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, which is why it spit out the value $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.

The other two numbers are $-1$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that $(e^{a})^{b}=e^{ab}$ when in complex numbers